# pubnub c# publishing message on channel without subscribing to channel

Tags: pubnub

Using the c# sdk for pubnub

Does anybody now how to publish a message on a channel withoud subscribing to the channel. I get an error in the UrlResponseCallback parsing the json string.

PubNub is instantiated with only the publish key.

Step 1 Instantiate pubnub with the publish key
Step 2 send txt message to channel, The channel allready exists between other clients.

Answer (score 1):

Both a valid **Subscribe key** and valid **Publish key** are required for a `pubnub.Publish()` method to succeed.  PubNub requires both keys.  However you do not need to subscribe to a channel before publishing.  You may publish freely to any channel without subscribing.

Comment: @beneke, if you are still stuck, feel free to reach out to us  support@pubnub.com, we're happy to get you moving...